# why do i get an error in my AndroidManifest that unexpected element <preference> found in <manifest><application><activity>

Tags: xml, flutter

```
<preference
                name="android-minSdkVersion"
                value="22" />
```

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\UPSTAR\Desktop\flutter projects\project\kigezi_guide\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:59: AAPT: error: unexpected element <preference> found in <manifest><application><activity>.
```

i tried removing

```
 <preference
                name="android-minSdkVersion"
                value="22" />
```

but when i build it comes back.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/android/app/build.gradle` and update these to 33,

```
compileSdkVersion 33 
targetSdkVersion 33
```